# Integral of Even and Odd functions

Tags: integration

Can I get help to prove or Disprove that -

$\int_{-a} ^a F_1(x)F_2(x)dx = 0 \ for \ a > 0$

when I know that $F_2$  is even function and $F_1$  is odd.

I would like to get the idea how to delete and extract Minus in integrals.

thanks!

Comment: Note that the product of an even function and an odd function is an odd function.

Comment: The condition $a>0$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the product of an even and an odd function is odd:

Proof:

define $G(.)=F_1(.)*F_2(.)$ where $F_1$ is odd and $F_2$ is even.

Then $G(-x)=F_1(-x)*F_2(-x)=-F_1(x)*F_2(x)=-G(x)$.

Then using the properties of definite integrals of odd functions, I think you will be able to find the answer from there.

Answer (score 2):

I will replace your two functions with $f$ and $g$ for convenience.

We have $h(x) = f(x)g(x) = f(-x) \cdot -g(-x) = -h(-x)$

Hence $$\int_{-a} ^a h(x) \ dx = \int_{-a} ^0 h(x) \ dx -  \int_{0} ^a h(-x) \ dx = \int_{-a} ^0 h(x) \ dx - \int_{-a} ^{0} h(x) \ dx = 0$$