# Definite integral of $\sin^{2m-1}x \cos^{2n-1}x$ from $0$ to $\pi$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I learned that
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2m-1}x \cos^{2n-1}x dx=\frac{1}{2}B(m, n).$$

Does this imply
$$\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2m-1}x \cos^{2n-1}x dx=B(m, n)?$$

Comment: I don't think that's right. Hint: You can determine the integral from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ with the substitution $u = \pi - x$.

Comment: @aschepler I have done as you hinted, that gives me the result of the integration is $0$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and the answers show some other related ways to prove the result is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2m-1}(x) \cos^{2n-1}(x) \ dx & \overset{\color{blue}{u = x -\pi/2}}{=} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2m-1}\left(u + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos^{2n-1}\left(u + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \ du\\
& =\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2m-1}\left(u \right)\left[-\sin(u)\right]^{2n-1} \ du\\
& =\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\underbrace{-\cos^{2m-1}\left(u \right)\sin^{2n-2}(u)}_{\color{purple}{\text{Even}}} \cdot \underbrace{\sin(u)}_{\color{purple}{\text{Odd}}}\ du\\
& = 0
\end{align}
Which is $0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ because [the integral over a symmetric interval of the product of an even and odd function is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1722092/695196).

Answer (score 4):

Substituting $x\to\pi-x$, we have:\begin{split}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2m-1}x \cos^{2n-1}x dx&=\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2m-1}(\pi-x) \cos^{2n-1}(\pi-x) dx\\&=-\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2m-1}x \cos^{2n-1}x dx.\end{split}